# Replace Value Of Fields Before Searching

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb, ado

To Increase Speed of search in the database, i want to do something like this:

If field TheFieldName (without any space in it) was equal with **test** then show the record(s)

how can i do it?

This did'nt work for me:

```
"SELECT * FROM TheTableName WHERE REPLACE(TheFieldName, ' ', '')=test"
```

**Error: Undefined function 'REPLACE' in expression**

Comment: What you are doing here will do the replace operation on every row in the TheTableName, before it can even start doing the comparison. This will not improve your search speed.

Comment: @DancingFool are you sure that speed of process in vb6 codes are equal with speed of process inside sql engine!?

Comment: I have searched internet again, it seems my adodb version in vb6 doesn't support replace command of sql :( it seems there is no way, i have decided to do the process in vb6 instead of sql commands :'(

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely to me that `replace()` is not known in SQL Server (or almost any other database).  But, check to be sure you are using the database you think you are.

Your query, as written, does have an error -- because you seem to want `test` as a string.  Does the query really look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TheTableName
WHERE REPLACE(TheFieldName, ' ', '') = 'test';
```

Note the quotes around `'test'`.

Comment: I'm using visual basic 6 on xp (Microsoft Activex data objects 2.8 Library)

Comment: I'm searching for something like TRIM but to remove all spaces in the string of search

Comment: Call OBJRS_RV_LOCAL.Open(SQL_STRING, OBJCN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
"SELECT * FROM TheTableName WHERE rtrim(ltrim(TheFieldName))=test"
```

Comment: Yes, this could work, for a different question. The spaces inside `TheFieldName` column will remain. All you are doing is removing leading and trailing whitespace.